# `fzero` function in matlab fails to find the root and keeps on generating error

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I am using MATLAB and I want to find the root of an equation F(x)-u=0. Here `u=0.2861` and

```
F=normcdf(sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu-1))+exp(2*lambda/mu)*normcdf(-sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu+1)).
```

The value of `lambda` and `mu` are both 1.

I typed the following code

```
[x,fval] = fzero(@(t) normcdf(sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu-1))+exp(2*lambda/mu)*normcdf(-sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu+1))-u, 10);
```

and hope this can help me find the root. I can show mathematically that this equation has unique root. However, I keep on getting the following error

> Error using `erfc` **Input must be real and full.**
>
> Error in `normcdf`>`localnormcdf` (line 128) `p(todo) = 0.5 * erfc(-z ./
>   sqrt(2));`
>
> Error in `normcdf` (line 50) `[varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] =
>   localnormcdf(uflag,x,varargin{:});`
>
> Error in
>   `Test`>`@(t)normcdf(sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu-1))+exp(2*lambda/mu)*normcdf(-sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu+1))-u`
>
> Error in `fzero` (line 363)
>           `a = x - dx;  fa = FunFcn(a,varargin{:});`

Then I did a "brutal force" method.

```
t = [0:0.001:20];
F = normcdf(sqrt(lambda./t).*(t/mu-1))+exp(2*lambda/mu).*normcdf(-sqrt(lambda./t).*(t/mu+1))-u;
plot(t,F)
```

I can clearly eyeball that `F(t)-u` is increasing in `t` and the root is around 0.4. My question is why `fzero` does not work in this case and is there a way to make `fzero` work?

Comment: I'm not entirely getting your problem. What is the `F`-call and I suppose, your code is `[x,fval] = ...`, which you call in a file named `Test.m`, right? Can you provide the values of `lambda` and `mu` for us?

Comment: @max my bad, sorry. lambda = mu =1. Yes, you are right. My code is the `[x,fval] = fzero(@(t) normcdf(sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu-1))+exp(2*lambda/mu)*normcdf(-sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu+1))-u, 10)` and it generates error. I will edit the post. Thanks!

Comment: `u` also misses (sorry, didn't saw this before)

Comment: At `t = 10`, the derivative `F'(10)`is almost zero, so `fzero` do not know in which direction it should go to reach the root. With a better starting value (`x0`=0.1), `fzero` output `0.41554` on my session.

Comment: @obchardon So, this `fzero` highly depends on the initial starting point? even if theoretically one can show that the root is unique? I have also tried to square my entire function `F` and use `fmincon` on `F^2`. That one seems less dependent on the initial starting point.

Comment: `fzero` is a numerical  method, a numerical method as nothing to do with analysis so `fzero` do not know that there is only one root, so yes `fzero` highly depends on the initial starting point.

Comment: Noticed that `fmincon` also use a numerical method so it also highly depends on the initial starting point. Finding the roots of a function is not an easy task for a computer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function does not change sign, which is required as the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) say:

> `x = fzero(fun,x0)` tries to find a point `x` where `fun(x) = 0`. This
>   solution is where `fun(x)` changes sign — `fzero` cannot find a root of a
>   function such as `x^2`.

I broke up your code to make it a bit clearer (at least for me).

```
lambda = 1;
mu = 1;
u = 1;

% break up function code
arg1 = @(t) +sqrt(lambda./t).*(t./mu-1);
arg2 = @(t) -sqrt(lambda./t).*(t./mu+1);
fnc = @(t) normcdf(arg1(t))+exp(2*lambda/mu).*normcdf(arg2(t))-u;
% call fzero to find the root
% [x,fval] = fzero(fnc, 10);

% plot
x = 0:0.01:10;
plot(x,fnc(x))
```

The function is not defined for any input `t` < 0 due to the `sqrt` in my function handle `arg`. So if you plot it for values `t` > 0, you see that it never passes zero.

**EDITED:** sign mix-up in the arguments. Thx *flxx* for pointing this out. Plot & code updated. The argument still holds.

[image: fnc(t)]

Comment: `normcdf(-arg(t))-u`, this part is wrong I am afraid...the things inside `normcdf` are not different by a sign. You can copy and paste my "brutal force" code, and the curve does cross 0.

Comment: @ftxx would you then please correct your example, as this is coming from your code: `@(t) normcdf(sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu-1))+...*normcdf(-sqrt(lambda/t)*(t/mu+1))..`

Comment: @ftxx BTW, the answer still holds. The function is not defined for negative values of `t` as the `art()` becomes complex. I will updated the figure as soon as you update your example code

Comment: Inside the 2nd `normcdf` it is `-sqrt(lambda./t).*(t/mu+1)` but in your code, it is `-sqrt(lambda./t).*(t./mu-1)`. So `+1` vs. `-1`. Am I missing sth? The 1st part inside the `normcdf`, we hare the same